# Pandas: Iteratively create (and fill) columns with .loc

Tags: python, pandas

Edit: solved underlying issue using merge

I'm trying to iteratively create columns while going through a for loop to show what the percentile values are for a given value (see below)

```
for i in range(temp.shape[0]):
    for j in range(3,temp.shape[1]):
       s = "".join([str((j-2)*20),'_Percentile'])             
       ouput.loc[(output['Condition 1'] == temp.iloc[i,0])
             & (output['Condition 2'] == temp.iloc[i,1]), s) = temp.iloc[i,j]
```

Which throws up the error "Syntax Error: Invalid Syntax", highlighting the closing bracket. The value of s appears to be correct (e.g. it throws out '20_Percentile', '40 Percentile', etc.). The underlying data is also fine - it outputs what I'd expect if I replace s with '20_Percentile', but obviously overwrites it each time it goes through the loop.

I'm new to Python so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Sam

Comment: Don't use iteration with pandas, use apply or built-in functions. Pandas is built on numpy and a suite of vector ops, which is way more efficient than iterations. You are defeating the purpose of pandas if you iterate, in a way.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you post some sample data, explain what you're trying to do, and an example of your expected output?

Comment: After starting to write out some sample data and exactly what I wanted to do I realised I could easily achieve the same thing with merge! Which also hopefully also means I'm not defeating the purpose of pandas as omdv pointed out. Thanks both of you for your help!